# How to upload the mobile app into PlayStore and AppStore which is generated by the Phonegap build?

Tags: app-store, phonegap-build, google-play

I am developing mobile applications using phonegap. We know that how to upload this app to "PhoneGap Build".
I tried to upload mobile app into the phonegap build and it is created apps for 6 platforms(Android, Ios, windows, bada etc..).
Now my question is "how to publish this app to the Play Store or App Store ?", do we need to download and manually upload it to the app store.
or is there any way to publish directly from the phonegap build to App or Play store?

Answer (score 0):

You need to download the finished and signed applications and then upload them to the respective stores.

Comment: So, there is no way to upload directly from phonegap build?

Comment: Not as far as I'm aware.

It's not a problem though, is it?

Use the normal browser method for Google and Application Loader for iOS.